# Is it good to use bullet image inplace of browser default bullets for UL to get cross browser result?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

Is it good to use bullet image inplace of browser default bullets for UL to get cross browser result?

Comment: What's your definition of cross browser result? In terms of margin/padding or the look of the bullet itself, or both?

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's a very stylized/graphics heavy site, I'd say no.  Users don't expect your webpage to have any particular look/feel...but they do expect it to be familiar and intuitive.  If you have a completely different theme and a completely custom look, then **yes**, go for it.  If you don't...let the user see what they're used to seeing.

Example:  Checkboxes look different on different browsers, but 99% of the time, the same to the user that's always using that browser on their computer.  Now using images/javascript to change what those checkboxes look like is slightly jarring, because they're suddenly unfamiliar.

If you're totally immersed in a different environment anyway (example: lots of graphics, black background, etc) then make your styles on anything fit that...for the standard-ish looking webpage that's very light on styles, I'd let the browser defaults prevail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using `list-style-image:url()`, then you pretty much enter a world of pain, since different browsers will position the image differently. If, however, you're using background images + padding, then you can indeed get consistent cross-browser results at almost no cost.